# Rails: After creating a record (e.g. a user) update another table (e.g. not the users table)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, callback

In my application I have users and fake posts. What I want: For each user, the fake posts should be displayed in a random order - however the (fake) timestamp associated with the fake-posts should be chronological. To make it clearer:

```
User A sees: 
- Post 1 created at 15.12.2016 - 14:00     
- Post 2 created at 15.12.2016 - 13:00    
- Post 3 created at 14.12.2016 - 23:00

User B sees:
- Post 3 created at 15.12.2016 - 14:00 
- Post 1 created at 15.12.2016 - 13:00
- Post 2 created at 14.12.2016 - 23:00
```

I have created a new table with those columns:

```
fakepost_id | user_id | fake_timestamp
```

My models look something like this:

```
# fakepost.rb
class Fakepost < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :randomized
end

# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :randomized
end

# randomized.rb
class Randomized < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :fakepost
end
```

Now I want to do the following (I only have pseudocode by now because I have no idea how to implement it :(...)

- When a new user is created...
- get all the fakeposts and...
- write into the new table for each fakepost: the fakepost_id, the user_id of the newly created user, and a random time in the past.

I know that in my user.rb model I can define an after_create callback, but how do I get all the fakeposts in my user model (they are not associated) and how do I write into another table (not the users table)? Or should I create a randomize.rb model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  Fakepost.all.each do |fp|
    @user.randomized.new(fakepost: fp)
  end

  # will insert @user first then the associated randomized(s)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to "/somewhere"
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

You can handle setting the random timestamp in the Randomized model.

If you are using Devise you would do this by [subclassing Devise::RegistrationsController](https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/2343176) and passing a block to super:

```
class MyRegistrations < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      Fakepost.all.each do |fp|
        resource.randomized.new(fakepost: fp)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually do use Devise for my User model, so your second answer worked perfectly! (And I am amazed at how easy and clean your solution is, I've experimented with different "after_save", "after_create" etc. callbacks). Thank you!